# "buy_now_url" doesn't work on magento 1.8 [SOLVED]

Tags: api, magento-1.8

I have a strange problem on Magento 1.8 using the REST API. 
When I do this request

```
GET http://magentohost/api/rest/products/8
```

I can retrieve a "buy_now_url" attribute, like this:

```
<buy_now_url>http://magento/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9Tb3VyY2VzL2FwaS9yZXN0L3Byb2R1Y3RzLzE,/product/1/</buy_now_url>
```

In Magento 1.7 using this URL I can directly add a product in the cart, in Magento 1.8 it doesn't work, I always obtain an empty cart. I used a simple product.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I found the real problem and solved it. Starting from Magento 1.8 it seems to be mandatory to specify a "form_key" parameter in the url to add product in the cart via querystring, as reported in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153691/magento-add-a-product-to-the-cart-via-query-string-without-form-key-parameter). To bypass this feature, I created a simple module with an AddController and used it to add products in the cart from external link, following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19157029/590434)
It works fine and I can add products to the cart using
http://mysite.com/frontname/add?product=123

Comment: if someone need it, I created a simple module to add products to the cart via querystring without specifying the "form_key" parameter: https://github.com/salgua/SalguaMagentoAddProduct

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to use the add to cart url

```
    /path/to/app/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]
```

So you would hard code the first part and then just call the id and add a quantity dynamically

More info here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring

Comment: No, it doesn't work... I tried both  http://yourstoreurl/checkout/cart/add/product/[id]/qty/[qty]
and http://domainname.com/checkout/cart/add?product=2880&qty=2 but it doesn't work in magento 1.8.

Comment: I think that the problem is in the "uenc" parameter that is autogenerated from Magento and it's required for any add to cart action. Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: How exactly are you implementing it and what happens? I'm not sure about it being necessary in 1.8 but my suggestion works on an older edition because I had to implement something similar before.

Comment: I have an external webapp that acts as "solution finder". When you find the right solution you can add it directly in the magento cart, on an external website. With Magento 1.7 it works fine, both using querystrings in url and buy_now_url from REST API. In Magento 1.8 it doesn't work

Comment: Assuming I'm understanding correctly, you are adding from outside the magento code base? If so, have you included the mage.php etc?